# Kivy right click menu

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I was trying to find a way to enable regular right click in Kivy, but without any luck.

I could find a way to disable the multitouch thing with:-

```
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')
```

But then the right click works just like left click, I need to be able to copy, cut, paste, etc..

I am making sort of an Information center GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

### Detecting right click

You can use the `on_touch_down` in combination with `if touch.button == 'right':` to detect a right click.

### Getting a context menu

TextInput has a method _show_copy_paste which opens up a Bubble as a context menu.

I do not think this is possible with Label. If you would like to implement it. I would suggest making your own label with these properties enabled and taking ideas from TextInput.

This is quite a lot of work. I would, therefore, prefer using TextInput with the property `readonly=True`. I have coded a version of TextInput which opens the Contextmenu aka Bubbles when right clicked. This is implemented in the sample app below. I coded and tested it on windows.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.base import EventLoop
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')



class RightClickTextInput(TextInput):   

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        super(RightClickTextInput,self).on_touch_down(touch)

        if touch.button == 'right':
            print("right mouse clicked")
            pos = super(RightClickTextInput,self).to_local(*self._long_touch_pos, relative=True)

            self._show_cut_copy_paste(
                pos, EventLoop.window, mode='paste')


kv_string = Builder.load_string("""
RightClickTextInput:
    use_bubble: True
    text: ('Palimm'*10+"\\n")*40
    multiline: True
    #readonly: True
""")



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Kivy has mobile devices in mind. If you are not doing anything with touch it might be worth checking out tkinter.